# Panolens + p5js: using image BLEND SCREEN function with SLIDERS for PANORAMA pictures

Tags: javascript, three.js, slider, p5.js, panoramas

I have the following question: How to show panorama images (that can be moved with mouse, or in cardboard googles) that can have a sliders controlling an image blend between two panoramas?

Description: I am trying to make an app, where user can see a panorama image and move around in it (I used PANOLENS for it), and then using sliders be able to make the images blend with each other. The blend is made using SCREEN BLEND function (basically, as the sliders move to one side, some brighter elements from one panorama start to appear on the other panorama - so in a way, two panorama images are displayed at the same time).

I think I kinda figured the way to do it for normal rectangular images - I use p5js library with IMAGE BLEND SCREEN function with 3 sliders - it is in the script called sketch.js:

```js
let DAYLIGHT;
let LAMPS1;
let LAMPS2;

function preload() {
  DAYLIGHT = loadImage('../img/OFFICEDL.JPG');
  LAMPS1 = loadImage('../img/OFFICEL2.JPG');
  LAMPS2 = loadImage('../img/OFFICEL1.JPG');
}
function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(1200,600).parent("recimage");
  DAYLIGHT.resize(1200,600);
  LAMPS1.resize(1200,600);
  LAMPS2.resize(1200,600);
  DLslider = createSlider(0, 255, 0).parent('slidersimage');
  DLslider.position(10, 0).parent('slidersimage');
  DLslider.style('width', '200px');
  L1slider = createSlider(0, 255, 0).parent('slidersimage');
  L1slider.position(10, 30).parent('slidersimage');
  L1slider.style('width', '200px');
  L2slider = createSlider(0, 255, 0).parent('slidersimage');
  L2slider.position(10, 60).parent('slidersimage');
  L2slider.style('width', '200px');

}

function draw() {
  background(0);
      blendMode(SCREEN);
const DLvalue = DLslider.value();
const L1value = L1slider.value();
const L2value = L2slider.value();
  tint(255, 255-DLvalue);
  image(DAYLIGHT,0,0);
  tint(255, L1value);
  image(LAMPS1,0,0);
  tint(255, L2value);
  image(LAMPS2,0,0);
  blendMode(BLEND);

}
```

Now for displaying the panoramas for now I have only used a workflow from tutorial to display the panorama, and for that I load three.min.js and panolens.js, and finally in the script main.js I use tell the app to display the panorama picture:

```js
const panoImage = document.querySelector('.pano-image');
const testPano1 = '../img/OFFICEDL.jpg';
const panorama = new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama(testPano1);
const viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer({
    container: panoImage,
});

viewer.add( panorama );
```

Finally, in my html it looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  </head>
  <body>
    
  
    <h1> PANORAMA TEST</h1>
    <p>
        This is the panorama view of the room
    </p>
    <div class="centering">
    <div class="pano-image"> </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        This is the stretched out panorama (equirectangular image view) with adjustable level of lighting
    </p>
    <div class="centering">
    <p id="recimage"></p>
    <p id="slidersimage"></p>
    </div>
    <p>
     End text
  </p>
  
    <script src="js/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sketch.js"></script>
    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/panolens.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
      
    

</body></html>
```

For now, altogether there is a panorama image on the top, and equirectangular version of it on the bottom, which has the sliders controlling it. Is there a way to implement similar control to the panoramic version?

Also, a side question: my sliders do not seem to position themselves relatively to the canvas, but rather to the whole website...anyone has any tips for that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!